# JQuerymobile Multipage

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-ajax

Can anyone send me a link to sample multi-page template where I can trigger an ajax call every time a page gets called/loaded? I need to show live data in the pages so it can't load once and show. when ever someone will move to a page it will load data from the server. ( i have the api that works fine with jsonp and loads data if I browse pages separately and refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the sample code given in this [link](http://www.gajotres.net/building-a-native-mobile-app-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile-1-4/).

Hope it helps!!